# How to pass data from one screen to the drawer?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one screen and I want to pass data from that screen to the drawer. My  drawer class looks like this:

```
class InitDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Auth auth;

  InitDrawer({this.auth});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String _name = auth.name;
    final String _email = auth.email;

    final drawerHeader = UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      accountName: Text(_name),
      accountEmail: Text(_email),
      currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
        ...
      ),
    );
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ...
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is my screen class which is passing the data

```
class QRScannerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/qr';

  final Auth auth;

  const QRScannerScreen(this.auth);

  @override
  _QRScannerScreenState createState() => _QRScannerScreenState();
}
class _QRScannerScreenState extends State<QRScannerScreen> {
    final auth = widget.auth;
    ...
    drawer: InitDrawer(auth: auth,),
    ...
}
```

And finally this is my Auth class/notified listener

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String _token;
  DateTime _expiryDate;
  String _userId;
  int _carId;
  String _email;
  String _name;

  String get name {
    return _name;
  }

  String get email {
    return _email;
  }
  ...
}
```

I think the whole problem comes from that the `auth` is null and when I try to view the drawer I am getting an error saying that my widget of type Text can not contain a text which is `null`. Because I am getting the auth with await and async maybe the data it is not getting there in time when screen loads and it is resulting in null. Maybe I have to use `setState`, but I am new to Flutter/Dart and I don't know where to use it.

Comment: The use of a future is most definitely causing the issue. What you may want to consider is using the Provider package as you're already using a ChangeNotifier. Otherwise you could make InitDrawer a StatefulWidget and use the auth object's addListener method to setState upon changes made. Which you'll need to use the built in notifyListeners() method once the data loads. Another option is to extend ValueNotifier instead which will automatically call notifyListeners(). That or use a FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `final auth = widget.auth;` and use `widget.auth` inside build method, or at least define `final auth` in `initState` method. But if you decide to use `initState` approach, keep in mind that you might need to update `auth` value inside your state class in `didUpdateWidget`